# How to get values from link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing `Latitude` and `Longitude` by link to `direction.html` file

```
.../direction.html?latlng=53.456269068499545,-6.220780313014984
```

how can I get this values to get lat and lng separately

Comment: did you attempt to do this yourself?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

You can use hashtag, that is passing the value latitude and longitude like this
 ursite/path#53.456269068499545,-6.220780313014984

```
var tag = window.location.hash;
tag = tag.substring(1,tag.length);
var co_ordinate = tag.split(",")
var latlng = co_ordinate[0]
var logitude = co_ordinate[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're passing a single variable, you could just split the data using the comma. The result would be an array.

```
latlng=53.456269068499545,-6.220780313014984
var res = latlng.split(",");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: I already did something like this:

Comment: function getDirection(dlatlng)
 { 
   var latlngStr = latlng.split(",");
      var destinationLatitude = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
      var destinationLatitude = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

Well Im not sure what language you are using to script the page. I have ideas for PHP.

```
//you get the variable being passed
if (isset ($_Get['longlat'];) {

$longlat = $_GET['longlat'];

//then you split them with explode
$longlat = explode(',', $longlat); 

$long = $longlat[0];
$lat = $longlat[1];
```

thats about it. read the manual on explode to get the correct syntax, but this is the gist of what you want i believe

Comment: I believe he is using javascript

Comment: I am using jquery/javascript ani want to pass a values between js

Answer (score 0):

You can use split to pull the string into an array, splitting it by the comma, then just assign each of the array's values to a new variable for lat and lng.

I would also parse the data into floats if you are using it as actual coordinate data later on, rather than just printing it.

For:

```
String latlng=53.456269068499545,-6.220780313014984;
```

Use:

```
var coords = latlng.split(",");
float lat = parseFloat(coords[0]);
float lng = parseFloat(coords[1]);
```

Comment: thanks I already did it : var latlngStr = latlng.split(",");
      destinationLatitude = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
      destinationLatitude = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
   alert(destinationLatitude);

Comment: destinationLatitude and other are global variables so I didn't use var

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out. Please remember to mark this question as answered so people stop replying haha!